# IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4, openid-connect, nonce

I have an ASSP.NET MVC web application `MyWebApp` which doesn't allow anonymous access to any page. There is an `IdentityServer4` configured and once the user tries to open `MyWebApp`, he gets redirected to IdentityServer login page. (Hybrid Flow)
The user does not login and stays on that IdentityServer login page for long enough so the `Nonce` cookie on `MyWebApp` expires (15min default lifetime).
If he then proceeds with the login in IdentityServer (successful) and gets redirected back to `MyWebApp`, he gets the following error:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException
> IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'.
> OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null,
> OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The
> nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set
> OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a
> 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.

But since the user was successfully authenticated in IdentityServer, when he tries to access `MyWebApp` again, he gets redirected to `IdentityServer` and back to `MyWebApp` without having to enter username/password again. Yet the initial error is annoying. Anyone ever had such issue when the 'login' flow has started and the user goes 'AFK' for long enough that the 'Nonce' cookie expires and he can't finish the final validation? What would be a good way to handle that scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The error `IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'` is telling you that the URL that you were on at the time you made a request from `MyWebApp` to `IdentityServer` is different from the URL that `IdentityServer` redirected you to after authentication.

I encountered this error by having `MyWebApp` listening on multiple URLs. For example, the user would connect to `www.MyWebApp.com`. He would click `Login` and would be rediected to `IdentityProvider`. He would log in to `IdentityProvider` which would then issue him a cookie proving his identity for `www.MyWebApp.com`. However, `IdentityProvider would then redirect him to my authentication endpoint (which I specified in my app) at` MyWebApp.com`. The change in the URL meant that his cookie was inaccessible to` MyWebApp.com` and the app would throw the error.

When I then refreshed the page, I was already on `MyWebApp.com`. Now, when he clicked `Login`, he would be redirected to `IdentityProvider`. Because he was already logged in there, a cookie would be generated and given to `MyWebApp.com` (which is different from the last time when the user connected on `www.MyWebApp.com`). When `IdentityProvider` POSTed to my auth endpoint, the cookie was accessible to the application and the user was successfully logged in.

TL;DR. The URL that user connects on must match exactly the URL that your `IdentityProvider` redirects to after a successful authentication. Depending on how your app is configured, different cookie rules will apply. In my case, a difference in encryption (http vs https) or in subdomain (www vs no-www) caused users to seemingly have the `IDX21323 error PII is hidden` at random

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I simply updated my Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect package to match the version numbers on my other OWin packages.

```
Microsoft.Owin [4.1.1]
Microsoft.Owin.Security [4.1.1]
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies [4.1.1]
```

, and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case exception IDX21323 was related to the use of the **http** protocol in the development environment.

The [current implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs#L671) in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler` (when redirecting to the authorization server) sets a **nonce cookie** for the user agent that has a hard-coded `SameSite=None` attribute. If the agent does not communicate via **https** protocol, the `Secure` attribute is not specified for the cookie:

```
new CookieOptions
{
  SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
  HttpOnly = true,
  Secure = Request.IsSecure,
  Expires = DateTime.UtcNow + Options.ProtocolValidator.NonceLifetime
}
```

Consequence of this implementation is that the user agent rejects nonce cookie (according to [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#fixing_common_warnings) if `SameSate` is `None`, `Secure` attribute is required).

It is therefore necessary to use **https** in the production environment. In the development environment, however, it is possible to use the Firefox browser as a user agent, which in the standard configuration [does not require](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#browser_compatibility) a secure context for `SameSite=None`.

Answer (score -1):

Inside OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications you can capture the error and just move on to the next middleware:

```
AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    if (context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
                    {
                        context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
```

If I can recall, IDS3 requires a nonce but IDS4 does not

Comment: what about openiddict?