# IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

I know there are several threads on the same but none of the solution works for me, is there any solution. The strange thing is when I run the application in IE it works where as in Edge I got into this issue

> IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'.
> OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null,
> OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The
> nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set
> OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a
> 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.

Here is the code

```
public class Startup
{
    // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
    string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

    // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Microsoft identity platform endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
    string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        }
    );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

I tired the options available but nothing works, is there any possible solution for this

Referred to this [OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536567/openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-was-null)

Comment: Show us what you tried, don't just tell us. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: No specific code I have created a sample application which I downloaded after creating an application from azure

Comment: @Developer have you found the solution to this? I am facing the same problem :(

Answer (score -1):

Please try updating your `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` package to match the version numbers on your other Owin packages, as discussed in [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457060/idx21323-requirenonce-is-pii-is-hidden-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcont).

```
Microsoft.Owin [4.1.1]
Microsoft.Owin.Security [4.1.1]
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies [4.1.1]
```

Make sure you have also updated to the latest version of Chrome if you are using Google Chrome, or test in other browsers. ([This guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/) discusses an issue with Chrome that was causing this error.)

Comment: I made them to 4.1.0 but still issue persists

Comment: Not sure if it is correct process `context.SkipToNextMiddleware();`

Comment: Are you able to share more details about what steps you tried?

Comment: I have just added this here `private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
       context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }`

Comment: this is not an answer