# Trying to login with Azure AFDS on multiple domains

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, owin, openid

I'm trying to connect to an Azure AD server with an Umbraco website.
To start off, I have no knowledge of Azure. There is a third party who administers the Azure part.

We use OWIN to connect to Azure via OpenID.
OnStartup:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app){
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions{
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters(){
                ValidateIssuer = false
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications{
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        });
    }
```

The SignIn function in the SurfaceController:

```
public void SignIn(string ReturnUrl = "/"){
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = ReturnUrl },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

Here come the non-working part.
If I test this site at a local domain (only available from within our office), it works.
If I test this site on a publicly-available staging domain, it works.
If I test this site on a live domain, it works.

But as soon as I change a sub-domain, I get send to the working domain with a "RequireNonce" error.
So for example:
https://customer.localdomain.com -> login -> I return logged in at https://customer.localdomain.com.
https://test.localdomain.com -> login -> I return to https://customer.localdomain.com (notice the domain), with a "Nonce-error".

https://customer.stagingdomain.com -> login -> I return logged in at https://customer.stagingdomain.com.
https://test.stagingdomain.com -> login -> I return to https://customer.stagingdomain.com (notice the domain), with a "Nonce-error".

https://www.livedomain.com -> login -> I return logged in at https://www.livedomain.com.
https://test.livedomain.com -> login -> I return to https://www.livedomain.com (notice the domain), with a "Nonce-error".

The complete error is:

```
IDX21323: 
RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. 
OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, 
OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. 
The nonce cannot be validated. 
If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.
RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
```

What can we do to resolve this problem? Our customer has a couple of subdomains (seperate sites) that all need this login functionality.
We've tried adding subdomains to a reply-list in Azure (well, the third party added them for us), but that didn't solve the problem.

Is it possible to just turn RequireNonce off somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you   [JamesHamil-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/3222814/jameshamil-msft.html) Posting your [suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/446430/how-to-solve-microsoftidentitymodelprotocolsopenid.html) as an answer to help other community members .

"The problem was that the time or automatic reference program service binding a custom domain name.
After the application network management is configured. The **Host IP** that modifies the custom domain name points to a **public IP** that is gateway."
Please try checking that your domain is configured correctly and points to the correct gateway."

Please refer the below links for further information:

. [Configure App Service with Application Gateway using PowerShell | MS DOC](https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/application-gateway/create-web-app) .

. [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457060/idx21323-requirenonce-is-pii-is-hidden-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcont) for similar issue.